# How does docker pauses containers in cgroups v2 in kernel versions lower than 5.2?

Tags: linux, docker, kernel, cgroups

The docker pause documentation says :

> The docker pause command suspends all processes in the specified
> containers. On Linux, this uses the freezer cgroup. Traditionally,
> when suspending a process the SIGSTOP signal is used, which is
> observable by the process being suspended. With the freezer cgroup the
> process is unaware, and unable to capture, that it is being suspended,
> and subsequently resumed. On Windows, only Hyper-V containers can be
> paused.

So if I'm using a distro like ubuntu 22 that has the 5.19 kernel which uses cgroups v2, but cgroups v2 implemented the freezer functionality since kernel version 5.2. How is then docker pausing my containers?

Tried to look for an answer all over the internet but couln't find out.